# Executing Get-Command with duplicate parameter

Tags: powershell

The following powershell command does not execute because `Get-Command` contains the `-Name` parameter twice:

```
Get-Command -Name "Get-Service" -Name "Spooler"
```

This works:

```
Get-Command -Name "Get-Service" -DisplayName "Spooler"
```

is there a workaround for this? Our application requires the use of Get-Command to prevent powershell code from being invoked **before it is validated.**

Our application processes powershell code that we do not write ourselves so we have to account for every possible scenario, a user may enter -Name but also enter -DisplayName.

Edit: more clarification:

```
#this code works, we have no control over the part after fhe first -Name
#and any solution has to be dynamic
Get-Command -Name "Get-Service" -DisplayName "Spooler"

#this does not work due to the duplicate -Name parameter
Get-Command -Name "Get-Service" -Name "Spooler"
```

Comment: Why can you not use the second version? This question is unclear to me.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Updated my post.

Comment: How does your "validation" process work? Also, [`Get-Help Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-5.1) probably has some useful information for you, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it uses the object that Get-Command returns, does some checks, coniditionals etc and then either executes it or not.

Comment: It's still not clear why you need `Get-Command`, but you might need to look into parsing out just the cmdlet name before calling `Get-Command` - or, alternatively, pay attention to what `Get-Command`'s `-Syntax` parameter gets you. See the link I provided in my previous comment.

Comment: The code (C#) needs `System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo` which is returned from a `System.Management.Automation.PSObject` (Get-Command)- to determine what type a command returns (for intellisense and such).

Now, for example. the command Get-WmiObject has different return types depending on what parameters are supplied.

Comment: `Get-Command` returns a `System.Management.Automation.CmdletInfo` object, not `CommandInfo`.  What are you *trying* to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's only a proof on concept but You can develop it this way:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.PreCommandLookupAction = `
{ 
    param($commandName, $commandLookupEvent)

    if ($commandName -eq 'Get-Command')
    {
        $commandLookupEvent.CommandScriptBlock = `
        {
            $getCommandArgs = @{}

            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args.Length; $i += 2)
            {
                $parameterName = $args[$i]
                $parameterValue = $args[$i + 1]

                if (-not $getCommandArgs.ContainsKey($parameterName))
                {
                    $getCommandArgs.$parameterName = New-Object Collections.ArrayList
                }

                $getCommandArgs.$parameterName.Add($parameterValue) | Out-Null
            }

            Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Get-Command @getCommandArgs
        }
    }
}

Get-Command -Name "Get-Service" -Name "Get-Item"
```

The output:

```
CommandType     Name             Version    Source                                                                                                 
-----------     ----             -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-Service      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                                        
Cmdlet          Get-Item         3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to execute `Get-Command -Name Get-Service -Name 'Spooler"` the part after the first -Name is not something that we have control over.